# 2016 Hyundai 70k miles, engine just replaced, now has an engine mis

Tags: engine, hyundai, rough-idle, elantra, random-misfire

I have a 2016 Hyundai Elantra that just had it's engine replaced 1k miles ago. After getting it back, at 400 miles the engine started to have a mis. Here are the details... When sitting at a stop light in drive holding the brake the RPM's jump around slightly. You can clearly hear the engine struggling to maintain a steady idle. When the car is at 1250-1750 RPM's it breaks up terribly, with the worst being 1500 RPM's. If it is at 1500 RPM's at 35-45 MPH while pressing the accelerator is bucks and sputters horribly. It does not (normally) happen above 2000 RPM's, but it has a few times. When you sit idling (in park) you can even hear the mis through the exhaust pipe. There is a clear problem with it that can only get worse. I have taken it back to the LAME dealership that replaced the engine (short block) under warranty 3 times and there tech can't find a problem. The last time I picked it up was 2 days ago and within 2 blocks it was doing the same thing. 1st visit they claimed they fixed the issue by replacing spark plugs. 2nd visit they found no issue, but reset the computer. 3rd visit, wait a week and then come back. I need help. Also, there is and has not been any engine light on. They said they need a code to know whats wrong. So they are parts replacers, not diagnosticians.

NOTE: It did not have this problem when I took it in, it had piston slap.

BTW: I just looked... this dealership has gobs of BBB complaints and strangely, none of them are their fault.

Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, your best bet here is to take it to a competent mechanic and then try to get the other shop to reimburse you.  Good luck with that, however.  You may have to take them to court.  Is this a NEW, REBUILT, or just a salvage engine that was installed?  If new or rebuilt, there may be some assistance from the supplier if the engine itself is defective.  Salvage, you're probably on your own.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Are there any codes (is the check engine light lit)? If so, what codes is the car showing? Also, was this done under warranty? The Hyundai should have a 10y/100k mile powertrain warranty. If so, you can always take it to a different Hyundai dealer and get it looked at.

Comment: It is a new engine (a short block, the bottom half) from Hyundai replaced under warranty. It has NO engine light, thus no code. I have two dealers in the area, the other are full of rude people that also have issues diagnosing. I used them before and it was a small disaster. IDK! My fear is that they will try to pull the 'no, it's something else unrelated that is wrong' and attempt to charge me... it WAS NOT doing this until they touched it.